# How to get nearest tile from touch with JSTileMap swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, tiled, jstilemap

I have just made a function that creates an object at the user's touch location but I want it to be auto aligned with the center of the tiles according to my tiled map.

Right now, I'm only able to place objects at my touch location instead of auto redirecting it to the nearest tile.

http://puu.sh/ggxOG/2785a2eeca.png (This is how my tiles look like 32x32)

JSTileMap functions

```
@class JSTileMap;

@interface TMXLayer : SKNode
@property (strong, nonatomic) TMXLayerInfo* layerInfo;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableSet* tileInfo;  // contains TMXTilesetInfo objects
@property (assign, nonatomic) CGSize mapTileSize;

/** Returns the width of the layer (layerGridSize.width * mapTileSize.width) */
@property (readonly,nonatomic) CGFloat layerWidth;

/** Returns the height of the layer (layerGridSize.height * mapTileSize.height) */
@property (readonly,nonatomic) CGFloat layerHeight;

/** Returns the JSTileMap that contains this layer */
@property (weak, nonatomic) JSTileMap* map;

- (CGPoint)pointForCoord:(CGPoint)coord;
- (CGPoint)coordForPoint:(CGPoint)point;

- (void)removeTileAtCoord:(CGPoint)coord;
- (SKSpriteNode*)tileAt:(CGPoint)point;
- (SKSpriteNode*)tileAtCoord:(CGPoint)coord;
- (int)tileGidAt:(CGPoint)point;
- (id)propertyWithName:(NSString*)name;
- (NSDictionary*)properties;

@end
```

Comment: Could you please share with me your final code to solve this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this this way to get the nearest tile.

```
var layer: TMXLayer = map.layerNamed("World1") // retrieve layer from tiled map
if let object = layer.tileAt(location) { // if there is a sprite(tile) at that position then set it as a var
position = object.position // update position var to the position of the sprite
}
```